# How can I solve day problem in appinsight alert?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-alerts

I have a problem with my kusto query. this kusto query is running inside the alert call. I tried to send a notification to our client via email.

Scenario :
I am trying to send messages between 7 am and 13 am on Saturday. (only Saturday) But I am getting messages also Sunday. There is nothing here below the query. I think it is related to app insight alert.

```
requests 
| extend Customer= trim_end('/', tostring(split(customDimensions.source, '//')[1]))
| extend alarmOK=iif(datetime_diff('minute', now(), timestamp) > 20, 1, 0) 
| extend issaturday=iif(dayofweek(timestamp) == 6d, 1, 0) 
| extend workinghour = hourofday(timestamp) 
| extend
    sendnotify1=iif(workinghour >= 7 and workinghour < 13, 1, 0),
    sendnotify2=iif(hourofday(now()) >= 7 and hourofday(now()) < 13, 1, 0)
| extend alarmmessage = "alert message"
| where timestamp > ago(24h) and Customer == "mycustomer"
| where issaturday == 1
| where workinghour >= 7 and workinghour < 13
| top 1 by timestamp desc
```

Comment: You `Customer` expression could probably also be simplified. Please provide an example for customDimensions.source  (in your post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All datetimes in Kusto are stored as UTC.
Use [datetime_utc_to_local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-utc-to-local-function) to get the timestamp in your local time zone, e.g.:

```
let timestamp = now();
print datetime_utc_to_local(timestamp, "Australia/Melbourne")
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoycxNLS5JzC1QsFXIyy/X0LTmKijKzCtRSEksSQVJxpeWJMeX5Mfn5Ccn5mjAlesoKDmWFpcUJeZkJur7puYk5ZcW5aUqaQIAOtfx6VQAAAA=)

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 2023-01-10T21:10:08.0645922Z |

P.S.
Your query could be simplified significantly.

- KQL supports the Boolean data type (bool).
- KQL supports datetime & timespan arithmetic.
  Even if for some reason you wanted to add a column named *issaturday* and then filter by it, it could easily be done like this:
   `| extend issaturday = dayofweek(timestamp) == 6d | where issaturday`

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let requests = materialize(
    range i from 1 to 100 step 1 
    | extend timestamp = ago(7d * rand())
);
// Solution starts here
requests 
| where     dayofweek(timestamp) == 6d
        and timestamp % 1d between (7h .. 13h)
        and now() - timestamp > 20m
```

| i | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-01-07T08:37:39.3449345Z |
| 80 | 2023-01-07T09:07:36.4794478Z |
| 83 | 2023-01-07T10:51:19.4051319Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WPTU7EMAyF95Fyh7dBSpDoD0jMApUjsOEEQXHbiCYpiUcFNIfHZdCI8c728/ee2xavLq4LwTt2mChRcRxyavCSGasrjDyCZ0LNy/F3o9VCjEIfR6pcMSA6phLcEr7JaAWp4tJECBhLjujBGX3XoTKt0p0lJ9AnU/LgEIUjIYTkpmwOHrc7wBtrtbJPWrUS8s9cGBKpYqZCWl0yaHXCts92srzylceN6N1c2BbDgEd/tt7LXTnfoPd4I5ajBHOY0TToH2Z7rU95MxZ3/%206ecd/FH%20ps6b9EAQAA)